# Dateformat.error We couldn't parse the value as DateTime Value (Works in PQ but broke in PBI)

Tags: powerbi

I created a table with dates in Excel & added to Power Query/Data Model which I imported into PBI

In PBI it is stating an error in the Query Editor being 'Dateformat.error We couldn't parse the value as DateTime Value'. It worked for a while but broke after I refreshed the data

There are no spaces etc on the source dates

FYI - My locale is Australia & hence the DD/MM/YYYY format

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing PowerBI locale? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/supported-languages-countries-regions

Comment: Since you show neither your code nor your data, it is difficult to figure out how to solve your problem. But somehow, in whatever code line happens to be returning that error, what you think is a datetime is a number representing a date. *In Excel and some other MS products, dates are stored as the count of days since 1/1/1900*. You need to re-examine your entire process and figure out where that might be happening. `44207` represents `1-Nov-2021`

Comment: I ended up just deleting the query, creating it again & it worked fine. This has happened quite a few times with Power BI that something does not work when it should. I recreate it & it works fine